# Force user to enter cell value if checkbox is selected on bootstrap datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jquery-events

I am having bootstrap datatable. I want to force user to enter data on a table's specific column on selected row. To be more clear I have a datatable which has three fields (select, studentName, result), what I want, when user select a student, they should enter result in text box. I don't know how to do that. I am new to Javascript, but something like this should help?

```
 $(function() {
    $(".checkbox").click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
       //get selected column value and user on blur event and show alert
 } 
}
```

but I don't know how to do that, please help me.

[image]

I have tried with below approach, but its not neat and clean,

```
$(function(){
            $('td').click(function(){
                $('#dbResultsTable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                    var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
                   if($row.find('td:eq(1) input').val()==""){
                   alert('please enter Result');
                   }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: It's called "form data validation" and there are thousands of SO questions about this.  You can write your own or use a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved it , here is the solution. Hope it helps someone

```
  function enableValidationOnSelectedCheckBox(id) {
    var checkboxSelect = document.getElementById('checkId_'+id);
     var requiredField= document.getElementById(id);
    if(checkboxSelect.checked!=true){
      // Do  nothing 
         $("#"+id).removeClass("focus");
     }
    else{
       if(requiredField.value.length>0){
         $("#"+id).removeClass("focus");
        }else{
        alert('Please don leave this field as empty');
        }
    }
}
```